# Where should I be catching touch events for painting on a QGraphicsScene?

Tags: qt, multi-touch, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I want to reimplement the Qt [fingerpaint](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/touch-fingerpaint.html) example using my [QGraphicsScene](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qgraphicsscene.html) rather than a QWidget.  However I cannot find an example of this so am unsure if I should capture the events at the view and pass them down to the scene or something else.  What is the advice here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about the [the pinch zoom example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/touch-pinchzoom.html)? It uses a QGraphicsView as the touch area.